# Display Upload Author & Get Uploaded Post ID

Tags: query

Working on a project with a lot of galleries & "attachment" post type queries.  It's all working great except I noticed in the Attachment Details box in the admin dashboard that Wordpress stores & displays the attachment upload author & uploaded to post.  So the question - does anybody have experience or know how to return the upload author & uploaded to post ID within the loop of a custom attachment query?

I've searched through the codex and stackexchange but haven't been able to come up with anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your attachment query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachments count as a built-in post type which is extremely similar to Posts and Pages. The field you're looking for is `post_author`.

If you have an attachment object:

```
$attachment->post_author
```

If you only have the attachment ID you can use

```
get_post_field( $attachment_id, 'post_author );
```

To get the actual Post the the attachment was originally uploaded to you can use:

```
$post->post_parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @howdy_mcgee for the first answer!  I actually was on that track as he was posting.  To answer the second part of my question of getting the uploaded to post_id, that is equivalent to the post parent which I grabbed simply with get_post( $post->post_parent );

Thanks for the help!